# Loading data from database into detailed view

Tags: iphone, xcode, sqlite

I'm reading data from a sqlite database however in my detailed view one of the data items is not showing correctly. It show what looks like random memory i.e. UIDeviceRGB...(I have two strings, one that works one that doesn't). I can't work out why but when I run the debug it returns null.

Here is my code in HydratedDetailData:

```
if (SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(detailStmt)) {
    double add = sqlite3_column_double(detailStmt, 2);
    NSString *address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", add];
    self.ClubAddress = address;
    [address release];
}
```

Any help work be greatly appreciated!

code from Clubs.m

```
#import "Clubs.h"

static sqlite3 *database = nil;
static sqlite3_stmt *detailStmt = nil;


@implementation Clubs

@synthesize clubID, clubName, ClubAddress, isDirty, isDetailViewHydrated;

+(void) getInitialDataToDisplay:(NSString *)dbPath {
    SQLAppDelegate *appDelegate = (SQLAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

        const char *sql = "select clubID, clubName from clubNames";
        sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            while (sqlite3_step(selectstmt)== SQLITE_ROW) {
                NSInteger primaryKey = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 0);
                Clubs *clubObj = [[Clubs alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:primaryKey];
                clubObj.clubName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 1)];


                clubObj.isDirty = NO;

                [appDelegate.clubArray addObject:clubObj];
                [clubObj release];
            }
        }
    }
                   else
                   sqlite3_close(database);
                   }

                   +(void) finalizeStatements {
                       if (database) sqlite3_close(database);

                     } 


                   -(id) initWithPrimaryKey:(NSInteger) pk {
                       [super init];
                       clubID = pk;

                       isDetailViewHydrated = NO;
                       return self;
                   }



-(void) hydrateDetailViewData {
    if (isDetailViewHydrated) return; 

    if (detailStmt == nil) {
        const char *sql = "Select ClubAddress from clubNames Where clubID = ?";
         if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &detailStmt, NULL) !=SQLITE_OK)
             NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating detail view statment. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
         }
    sqlite3_bind_int(detailStmt, 1, clubID);

    if (SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(detailStmt)) {
        double add = sqlite3_column_double(detailStmt, 0);
        NSString *address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", add];
        self.ClubAddress = address;
    }
    else
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while getting the address of club. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    sqlite3_reset(detailStmt);

    isDetailViewHydrated = YES;
    }


-(void) dealloc {
    [ClubAddress release];
    [clubName release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps if you used the %d formatter in your [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", add]; call.

(%@ is generally for strings, %d is for doubles)

After our little discussion-athon, this should fix what ails you.

```
if (SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(detailStmt)) {
     char *db_text = sqlite3_column_text(detailStmt, 2);
      NSString *address = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: db_text];
      self.ClubAddress = address;
}
```

This will pull the text value from the database and convert it into an NSString*. (hopefully)....

Comment: Thank you for your response however now the app crashes when trying to load detailed view. I can see in the debug that it is now getting the address items but then crashes.Any other suggestions.@omgz0r

Comment: Releasing something that you haven't explicitly allocated is sometimes a bad idea. Maybe if you remove the [address release] line. I know it feels wrong, but the justification on apple's side seems to be that, since the string was technically allocated inside the stringWithFormat: method, it will handle the deallocation as well.

Comment: I don't mean to be a pest that app does not crash now but it only returns 0 instead of the text.@omgz0r

Comment: I don't follow, what do you need to be returned? Text, or a number?

Comment: Text. It does not return the string in the view it only shows 0 i.e instead of showing the address 4 sample street, it shows 0.@omgz0r

Comment: So, unrelated to your posted code block, but in the method? If it *is* related to your posted code block, you will have to look at fetching a string from sqlite, and storing that as a NSString right off the hop. If not, can you show the code in question?

Comment: Okay; is the ClubAddress column a varchar in your sqlite3 database?

Comment: You will have to pull the value from the database using sqlite3_column_text. I have edited my original answer to provide you with the source that should work with this, though it has been awhile for me.

Comment: I now get the following warning and the program crashes; "Initialization discards qualifiers from pointer target type"@omgz0r

Comment: I'm out of ideas now. Note that what you'll need to do here is similar if not exactly the same as what you did for the clubName. Just make sure that the SQL you're generating is actually returning records, and make sure to check for nil's. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

i had such a problem for reading double values, some of values read right but some read as 0 ! i have tried many things but at last my problem was solved by defining variables globally. i have defined the locally in .m file but the solution was to define them in .h file.i hope it can solve yours too.
good luck